# Overlaying values of one raster over another

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, merge

I have two rasters. One is larger and binary called mask (all values are either 0 or 1). The smaller raster fits inside this raster but has a much smaller extent smallerMask. All its values are 1. Where it sits above the larger raster, the larger raster is populated with 0s. I want to replace that area of 0s with the 1s from the smallerMask. Thought this would be easy.

`(("mask" + "smallerMask") = 2 OR ("mask" + "smallerMask") = 1) = 1`

However, I just get output along the smaller raster extent. I made sure that the larger one was selected as the extent. Why is this happening?

I've also tried `merge` but it keeps the original values.

EDIT: I figured out a workaround by using both layers to build a virtual raster but I would really like to know how to do this with *raster calculator*

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured this out.

1. Ensure the smaller raster actually has the same extent as the larger raster, but with a bunch of *nodata* values outside the AOI.
2. use `r.null` to convert the *nodata* to 0s in the smaller raster.
3. Use the following expression in `raster calculator`:

`(("mask1" + "mask2") = 2 OR ("mask1" + "mask2") = 1) = 1`

And that's it.